# MATLAB indexing

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have only 2 columns in my array (x):

Type of stimuli - 1-4 
Response to stimuli 1-4

All I need to know is the number of times each stimulus was responded to in a certain way.

What I want is a 2x2 (`z`) matrix showing this. I have used the following code to find the number of times that each occurs:

```
y = arrayfun(@(t)nnz(x==t), x);
```

Which gives me a two column matrix with the same length as `x`

But is there a way to index `x` to give me the corresponding details in `y` so that I can put it into `z`.

Comment: could you post an data example and the solution you wish to achieve with it? would the resulting matrix be 4x4 (4stimuli and 4 responses)

Comment: The data is really big so say

Comment: You have 4 different types of stimuli, right? So one of the dimensions of `z` would have to be `4`. How many different responses are there? If your data is large, you can create a *small, representative* sample to give us an idea of what you're trying to do.